# Add <Script ... /> tag within <Head ... /> tag in ServerControl (ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, servercontrols, servercontrol

I'm gonna use JQuery files in my custom ServerControl , thus I have to add below line within Head tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

How can I do it in ServerControl with C#

Comment: You have to add your .js file in Solution Explorer

Comment: I've already done it, but the Script tag doesn't add within Head tag !!!

Comment: You have to add it manually into your ASPX file, or register it from your code. See my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can register custom scripts using the [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2552td66(v=VS.90).aspx) during the page load. Alternatively, you can just include the script in your .aspx page. If this is a public server control, the first method is probably more preferable.

EDIT: alternatively you can register scripts in the `<head>` tag of the page as follows:

```
HtmlGenericControl jqueryInclude = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
jqueryInclude.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
jqueryInclude.Attributes.Add("src", "http://<path to jQuery>");
Page.Header.Controls.Add(jqueryInclude);
```

Comment: I've tested it, It adds the Script tag within the Form tag, I wanna add it within Head tag !!!

Comment: Awesome, Thanks dude, But one question, How should I write the Path of file? I save the file in `JavaScriptFiles` folder in ServerControl Solution !!!

Comment: This doesn't add to the head