# How to append script tag dynamically in asp.net user control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dynamic, onload, onerror

I have user control (myUserControl.ascx). in that i am trying to append script tag and assigning "src" dynamically and then checking onload and onerror events, but it seem to be not working.I am calling PerformDynamicJS on button click.

```
function PerformDynamicJS(){
var scriptGoogle = document.createElement("script");
scriptGoogle.type = "text/javascript";
scriptGoogle.src = "myscript.js";
scriptGoogle.onload = function (evt) {
            alert('Inside onload');
        }
 scriptGoogle.onerror = function (evt) {
            alert('Inside on error');
        }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117712/add-script-tag-within-head-tag-in-servercontrol-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your newly created  tag to the document:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptGoogle);
```

Comment: I cannot get my head tag , as it is not present in my user control. It is present in my master page.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's a user control or not. You have access to entire document from within your JavaScript function "PerformDynamicJS". If you don't have a <head> section on your page then use "document.body" instead of "document.getElementsByTagName(...)".

Answer (score 1):

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("src", "url to the script file here");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

I looked for "onload" with scripts before, I don't remember finding such event. I ended up writing a timer-based js code to frequently check for an object that is expected to be defined in the script that is being downloaded. So, it's either that you do that, or: why not simply not do anything from within the code that inserted the script tag - instead, you have a perfectly timed moment when your script is ready: add "unwrapped" code to the script itself (e.g. `alert("I, the script, loaded and I'm ready with these functions that I provide");`.

And, there is no "on error" case here: the script will either download or it will not (for whatever reason: unavailability, connectivity, server-error, etc). If it does [download], any errors that may be occurring while that script is being executed/used are not really transport-related (those errors should be treated the same way you treat any other script error), so your intention with "onerror" here isn't a fit (IMO). +1 :)

EDIT: If it doesn't download, then it will not execute, and you will not be able to use it. If your client code is really waiting, then you'll have to write some kind of timer-based timeout logic; for example, after the "add to head" line above, do something like this:

```
window.setTimeout(function()
{
    // object/variable "newScriptObject" is defined in the new script
    if(!newScript)
    {
        // script timed out; let's proceed with plan B
    }
    else
    {
        // script ready, proceed as planned;
        // although, like I said, I think it's more precise if you execute this code in your myscript.js instead - as maybe that code will be ready before the 5 sec assumed here
        // alternatively, use window.setInterval to check for objects defined this script every so milliseconds, in which case, when you find the script, don't forget to stop that timer (window.clearInterval)
    }
}, 5000); // wait 5 sec for the new script
```

**Finally, there is no such thing as "partial download" in this context.** A sane browser will not start executing a script that hasn't been fully, not only downloaded, but also parsed (interpreted). The "interpreted" part is why you'll see JS errors that often point to unrelated location when you miss a brace somewhere or due to other syntax errors. Missing a brace, at least, is in this category, as such syntax error practically "shifts" (kind of) code blocks completely, making it impossible to figure out what's what. Sorry for going a little bit off-topic here.